# annoying warnings for OcTreeBaseImpl.h/OcTreeIterator.hxx

Tags: moveit, octomap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm building MoveIt from source (indigo-devel branch for most packages), and getting this warnings everywhere (because octomap in included everywhere).
Is there a fix for octomap to get rid of them?

I'm using OSX 10.9, and Clang 5.1

```
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/octomap/octomap.h:37:
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/octomap/OcTree.h:38:
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/octomap/OccupancyOcTreeBase.h:44:
/opt/ros/indigo/include/octomap/OcTreeBaseImpl.h:262:11: warning: class member
      cannot be redeclared [-Wredeclared-class-member]
    class leaf_iterator;
          ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/octomap/OcTreeIterator.hxx:260:11: note: previous
      declaration is here
    class leaf_iterator : public iterator_base {
          ^
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/192975/annoying-warnings-for-octreebaseimpl.h/octreeiterator.hxx/) by [sk2009](https://answers.ros.org/users/20232/sk2009/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2014-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I submitted a pull request, and it has been merged.
Of course you ought to have done that last year in the first place ;)

---

Originally posted by [arntanguy](https://answers.ros.org/users/24511/arntanguy/) with karma: 16 on 2015-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0